# table alternative: grid list

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a form containing 10-20 input-type-text fields and their labels. The number of elements varies, so I'm searching for a solution to output all fields and labels and let them automatically adjust to a grid:

```
Label1: [________] Label2: [____] Label3: [________]
Label4: [___]      Label5: [__________]   
Label6: [_______________]         Label7: [________]
Label8: [________________________________]
```

The length of labels and input fields also varies, so I can't define, that the maximum number of fields per row is i.e. three.

Is this possible with css (i.e. flexbox), or do I've to use jquery?

Comment: Is the picture above the desired output layout?

Comment: It's just an example. The layout should be dynamic.

Comment: The answer to your question would be just "yes". Any further explanation would result into "the answerer writes your code for you". -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the below:

```
   <div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <div class="formElement"><label>label</label><input type="text"  /></div>
    <div class="formElement custom"><label>label</label><input type="text"  size="4" /></div>
    <div class="formElement"><label>label</label><input type="text" /></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="formElement"><label>label</label><input type="text" /></div>
    <div class="formElement"><label>label</label><input type="text"/></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="formElement"><label>label</label><input type="text" /></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and the css

```
   .wrap{
  width: 600px;
}

.wrap > div{
  display:flex;
  margin: 5px 0
}

.formElement{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
}

label{
  margin:0 5px;
}

input{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.custom{ 
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbOJJa

Comment: Yes, nearly perfect, but I want to change the width of the input fields (i.e. the postal code should be shorter than a city field).

Comment: Edited my answer to allow for custom size inputs ("custom" class on formElement). Just add size="4" or whatever you want on the input fired.

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as correct (green tick) if it solved the issue :)